# Updating to MassTransit 5.3.0 gives ScopedConsumeContextProvider not registered

Tags: masstransit

I am using MassTransit 5.2.0. I have to update because we are going to use AWS, and it requires the amqps protocol for using rabbit mq which is not supported in 5.2.0. I eventually probably want to update to version 5.5.6. How ever I get this error when I update the library:

```
2023-09-14 16:01:09.0917|ERROR|MassTransit.Messages|R-FAULT rabbitmq://localhost/dqportal/dq_audits db270000-1fd6-00ff-3025-08dbb52b0be4 
DQ.Audits.IntegrationEvents.Contracts.IAuditEventOccurredIntegrationEvent DQ.Audits.IntegrationEvents.Consumers.AuditEventOccurredConsumer(00:00:00.0013801) 
No service for type 'MassTransit.Scoping.ScopedConsumeContextProvider' has been registered.
Exception:System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'MassTransit.Scoping.ScopedConsumeContextProvider' has been registered.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at MassTransit.ExtensionsDependencyInjectionIntegration.ScopeProviders.InternalScopeExtensions.UpdateScope(IServiceScope scope, ConsumeContext context)
   at MassTransit.ExtensionsDependencyInjectionIntegration.ScopeProviders.DependencyInjectionConsumerScopeProvider.MassTransit.Scoping.IConsumerScopeProvider.GetScope[TConsumer,T](ConsumeContext`1 context)
   at MassTransit.Scoping.ScopeConsumerFactory`1.Send[TMessage](ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
   at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.ConsumerMessageFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.ConsumeContext<TMessage>>.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
   at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.ConsumerMessageFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.ConsumeContext<TMessage>>.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
   at GreenPipes.Filters.TeeFilter`1.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next)
   at GreenPipes.Filters.OutputPipeFilter`2.SendToOutput(TInput context, IPipe`1 next, TOutput pipeContext)
   at GreenPipes.Filters.OutputPipeFilter`2.SendToOutput(TInput context, IPipe`1 next, TOutput pipeContext)
   at GreenPipes.Filters.DynamicFilter`1.Send(TInput context, IPipe`1 next)
   at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.DeserializeFilter.Send(ReceiveContext context, IPipe`1 next)
   at GreenPipes.Filters.RescueFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<TContext>.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next)
```

It happens the moment I update from MassTransit 5.2.3 -> 5.3.0. So 5.2.3 is the last one working with my code. The 5.3.0 is the first one where it fails.
I assume I have to do something in the registration of MassTransit to make it work again. Somehow register that ScopedConsumeContextProvider, but I really have no idea.

This is my initialization code:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       // other registrations ...
       services.AddEventBus(Configuration);
    }

    public static class SetupEventBusTask
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddEventBus(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.Scan(scan => scan.FromAssemblyOf<AuditEventOccurredConsumer>()
                .AddClasses(c => c.Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Consumer"))).AsSelf().WithScopedLifetime());

            if (configuration.GetValue<bool>("Queue:Enabled"))
                configureEventBusWithQueue(services, configuration);
            else
                configureEventBusInMemory(services, configuration);

            services.AddSingleton<IBus>(s => s.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>());
            services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, BusService>();
            services.AddScoped<IIntegrationEventStore, IntegrationEventStore>();

            return services;
        }

        private static void configureEventBusWithQueue(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.AddSingleton(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
                IRabbitMqHost host = cfg.Host(
                    configuration.GetValue<string>("Queue:HostName"),
                    configuration.GetValue<string>("Queue:VirtualHost"),
                    h => {
                        h.Username(configuration.GetValue<string>("Queue:Username"));
                        h.Password(configuration.GetValue<string>("Queue:Password"));
                    });

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, configuration.GetValue<string>("Queue:QueueName"), endpoint =>
                {
                    endpoint.Consumer<AuditEventOccurredConsumer>(provider);
                });

                //cfg.UseMessageScheduler(new Uri(configuration.GetValue<string>("Queue:SchedulerQueueUri")));
                cfg.UseNLog();
            }));
        }

        private static void configureEventBusInMemory(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.AddSingleton(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.UseNLog();
            }));
        }
    }

    public class BusService : IHostedService
    {
        private readonly IBusControl busControl;
        private readonly ILogger<BusService> logger;
        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

        public BusService(
            IBusControl busControl,
            ILogger<BusService> logger,
            IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.busControl = busControl;
            this.logger = logger;
            this.configuration = configuration;
        }

        public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            logger.LogInformation("Starting eventbus");

            string hostname = configuration.GetValue<string>("Queue:HostName");
            string virtualhost = configuration.GetValue<string>("Queue:VirtualHost");
            string username = configuration.GetValue<string>("Queue:Username");
            string queuename = configuration.GetValue<string>("Queue:QueueName");

            logger.LogInformation($"Configuring Event Bus with Values: {hostname}, {virtualhost}, {username}, {queuename}.");

            await busControl.StartAsync(cancellationToken);

            logger.LogInformation("Started eventbus");
        }

        public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            logger.LogInformation("Stopping eventbus");
            await busControl.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
            logger.LogInformation("Stopped eventbus");
        }
    }
```

The consumer code I have simplified to the most simple consumer that only writes a log. I do not think the problem lies there.

Comment: I think I got it working now: I added  "services.AddMassTransit(opt =>
            {
                opt.AddConsumer<AuditEventOccurredConsumer>();

            });"

Answer (score 0):

Okay, just after popping the question I found the answer myself! You have to add/register the consumer to MassTransit like this:

```
        private static void configureEventBusWithQueue(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.AddMassTransit(opt =>
            {
                opt.AddConsumer<AuditEventOccurredConsumer>();

            });
            // the other code ...
        }
```

Comment: Any information why this is would be appreciated though. It is just cargo cult, I copied something from another piece of code then it worked.